# Can Blender export an colored SVG?

Tags: rendering, svg

With Blender 3.4 I am trying to export an SVG image but i got an image without color only the lines.

Although i am clicking on "fill Contours" under Freestyle SVG export.

So is there a Problem or using Blender i can not export an colored SVG file?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/render/render_freestyle_svg.html#exportable-properties